# Switching between side by side text windows in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an eclipse window with two tabs open side by side so that I can see the text of both files simultaneously. Is there a keyboard shortcut that allows me to switch which window I am editing?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, it  will pop-up a small context menu were with all editors and windows, by default it switch you to the next editor in the list. And
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>F6</kbd> goes to the previous editor in the list.

It's not exactly what you asked for, but i cannot found simple shortcut for switching windows. You can read [this article](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2006/11/20/swap_windows_in_eclipse) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own perspectives (Window --> Save Perspective As...) and easily switch between them:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>       Next perspective
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> Previous perspective